# foreign key showing undefined django ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

in this scenario when put the name of foreign key in p tag with js, it is showing undefined but its getting the inpuput as the proper user but not not able to show it because it is saying undefined

**js code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // $('#submit').onclick(function(){
      //   $('#message').val=''
      // })
      $(document).on('submit','#post_form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"{% url 'create' %}",
            data:{
                message: $('#message').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                
            },
            success:function(){
                window.location = url;
            }
        });

      });

        setInterval(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:"{% url 'comments' %}",
                success:function(response){
                   $('.display').empty();
                   for(var key in response.comments){
```

**this is where it shows undefined, is there any way to convert it to string**
console.log(response.comments[key].user);

```
                       var temp = "<div class='message_area'><p id='messagetext'>"+response.comments[key].message+"</p></div>"
                       $(".display").append(temp);
                   }
                },
                error:function(response){
                    console.log("no data found")

                }

            }); 
        }, 500);

    });
```

**views.py**

```
def create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    author = request.user
    message = request.POST['message']

    message = comments(user=author,message=message)
    message.save()
```

**models**

```
class comments(models.Model):
userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
date = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user} comments'
```

Comment: hi, first you don't need to define an `Id` field for models in django, because always there would be an automatically generated one. second in the `views.py` inside the `create` function you're using the word `message` for everything! why? isn't there any characters to use? what you did there will result in unusual errors and bugs many-times so avoid doing that. but for the question I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

using Django template syntax in the js codes is not wrong but it could be better if we don't do that.
instead of `data:{ message: $('#message').val(); csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),},`
it could be writing in the html, inside the form part. and the js could be:

```
<form id="form_id" ......>
{% csrf_token %}
 <!-- other fields of the form -->
 </form>

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"{% url 'create' %}",
        data:$("#form_id").serialize();
        success:function(){
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
```

well, thats not enough for your case, you have problem in another part of the code. you didn't provide the views function which returns the comments and it seems that the problem is there, at this time you could use `console.log(response.comments[key]);` to figure out what data is returned then use the information to correct the code

Comment: yes it is returning all json response but it is showing user_id = 1, thats true i have created only one user, what is the way to convert into string and show the author of post?

Comment: you mean instead of the id, you need the user instance?

Comment: if so, you need to some magic ;). instead of returning json response and use data in javascript frontend. create a template file, use [Djangos built-in `render_to_string` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) and render a template with the required queryset data. then return the rendered template to ajax and now show the response to user. render_to_string doesn't need the request and will do the same as `render` method. in js part you could use `append, innerHtml, ...` to attach the response to the page (dom);